# Can't format angular timestamp

Tags: angular

I get the date from firebase as a string (not sure if that's the problem) and then I can display it simply with:
`{{ post.data.date }}` 
 and it displays: Timestamp(seconds=1544623520, nanoseconds=401000000) 
 The problem is when I give it a date format (`{{ post.data.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}`) it gives an InvalidPipeArgument error, but If I add * 1000 `{{ post.data.date * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}`
 the error is gone but nothing gets displayed.
The full error without that * 1000 :
 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Timestamp(seconds=1544623520, nanoseconds=401000000)" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: The DatePipe expects a JavaScript `Date` object. You appear to have something else. I don’t know Firebase but you should check what the actual type of that is and maybe convert it into a `Date` first. If you do that from TypeScript (instead of in the Angular template), you will also get type support to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually tried changing it to Date but I get the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unable to convert "Timestamp(seconds=1544623520, nanoseconds=401000000)" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

That's because `"Timestamp(seconds=1544623520, nanoseconds=401000000)"` isn't a valid JS Date, nor a string that the Date constructor can interpolate. The same thing can be seen in any JS environment:

```
new Date("Timestamp(seconds=1544623520, nanoseconds=401000000)");
// --> Invalid Date
```

You could either convert the value before binding or in your own Pipe before the DatePipe:

```
const timeStamp = "Timestamp(seconds=1544623520, nanoseconds=401000000)";
let [,res] = timeStampe.match(/seconds=(\d+)/);
return new Date(+res * 1000); // because JS epoch times are milliseconds
// --> Wed Dec 12 2018
```